# Calling golang function from python using C

Tags: python, c, go, cgo

I have following code in my myPyTest.c file

```
#include<python/Python.h>
#include "libtest.h"

static PyObject * callThatFunc(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    const char *a, *b, *c;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "S", &a, &b, &c))
        return NULL;
    printf("%s", returnThis(a));
    return PyString_FromString(b);
}

static PyMethodDef BarMethods[] = {
    {"call_bar",  callThatFunc, METH_VARARGS,
        "Execute a shell command."},
   {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
initbar(void)
{
    (void) Py_InitModule("bar", BarMethods);
}

int main() {
    printf("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

check [this](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html) for above code

Now I have following golang code in my_go_call.go file.

```
package main

import "C"

//export returnThis
func returnThis(myString *C.char) *C.char {
    var result *C.char
    myStringGo := C.GoString(myString)
   result = C.CString("Hello, " + myStringGo)
   return result
}

func main() {
}
```

I have created shared library using command (MAC)
    `go build -ldflags -s -buildmode=c-shared -o libtest.so my_go_call.go`

Then I have setup.py file to build c extension for python. Code of setup.py as follows

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('bar',
                libraries = ['test'],
                library_dirs = ['/path/to/lib'],
                sources = ['myPyTest.c'])
setup (name = 'PackageName',version = '1.0',description = 'This is a demo package',ext_modules = [module1])
```

Now i am building and installing my extension using following commands

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

whenever I call my function in python interpreter i get following error.

```
>>> import bar
>>> dir(bar)
['__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'call_bar']
>>> bar.call_bar('a','b','c')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

Comment: In `myPyTest.c`, try to change the second arg of `PyArg_ParseTuple` from `"S"` to `"sss"`.

Comment: @putu Yes it worked. Thanks.